# How to define child routes for specific params?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

In React-Router-Dom 6 I am using `useRoutes` and so I build a route object. I have a route where I want the top of the route to have a layout, and then different outlets based on the param.

So for example:

```
/wizard/step1 -> Step1Page
/wizard/step2 -> Step2Page
```

The way I built this, looks like:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/wizard/:step',
    element: <WizardLayout />, // this has an <Outlet />
    children: [
      {
        path: '/wizard/step1',
        element: <Step1Page />,
      },
      {
        path: '/wizard/step2',
        element: <Step2Page />,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This throws an error, saying that child paths "must begin with full paths of their parents". This means that the layout should have a path like:

```
{
  path: '/wizard',
  element: <WizardLayout />,
  children: [ ... ],
}
```

However, doing it like this makes the children elements not recognize the `:step` param when calling `useParams` because it's not actually defined in the route.

To reiterate, I want the layout to apply to all routes of type `/wizard/:step`, and to have specific elements in specific `:step` params. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, you can't nest the absolute path `"/wizard/step1"` under the absolute path `"/wizard/:step"`. To have a dynamic path segment `step` available to `WizardLayout` then you have a few options.

1. Move the children routes into a `switch` statement in `WizardLayout` to replace the `Outlet`.

   ```
   const router = createBrowserRouter([
     ...
     {
       path: '/wizard/:step',
       element: <WizardLayout />,
     },
     ...
   ]);
   ```

   ```
   const WizardLayout = () => {
     const { step } = useParams();

     const getStep = () => {
       switch(step) {
         case "step1":
           return <Step1Page />;

         case "step2":
           return <Step2Page />;

         default:
           return null;
       }
     }

     return (
       <>
         ... Wizard Layout UI ...
         {getStep()}
         ...
       </>
     )
   };
   ```

   [image: Edit wizardly-easley-thq4df]
2. Update the route declarations so the nested routes can work and use the `useMatch` hook in `WizardLayout` to get a match to a `"/wizard/:step"` path.

   ```
   const router = createBrowserRouter([
     ...
     {
       path: '/wizard',
       element: <WizardLayout />,
       children: [
         {
           path: 'step1',
           element: <Step1Page />,
         },
         {
           path: 'step2',
           element: <Step2Page />,
         },
       ],
     },
     ...
   ]);
   ```

   ```
   import { Outlet, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

   const WizardLayout = () => {
     const match = useMatch('/wizard/:step');
     const { step } = match?.params;

     return (
       <>
         ... Wizard Layout UI ...
         <Outlet />
         ...
       </>
     )
   };
   ```

   [image: Edit react-router-6-how-to-define-child-routes-for-specific-params (v2)]

Answer (score 0):

in react router using :step means that you want the route to include dynamic value but in your case there is nothing dynamic, so change the code to

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/wizard',
    element: <WizardLayout />, // this has an <Outlet />
    children: [
      {
        path: 'step1',
        element: <Step1Page />,
      },
      {
        path: 'step2',
        element: <Step2Page />,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

where the layout has the Outlet and it will render the child route accordingly

A case where if you do want a dynamic route say you want an id to be part of a route which you will get by clicking something then that is when you use the :id to set it as part of the route